# std::optional as a template parameter for std::atomic

Tags: c++

Is it legal to use next code with initialization:

```
std::atomic<std::optional<uint64_t>> value{std::nullopt};
const auto loadedValue{value.load()};
assert(false == loadedValue);
```

I read that template type for `std::atomic` should be TriviallyCopyable but `std::optional` is not.

Note: Without initialization with `std::nullopt` I had undefined behaviour, namely `true == loadedValue`.

Comment: Note that `std::atomic<std::optional<uint64_t>>` will very likely not be lock-free. On the contrary, `std::atomic<std::optional<uint32_t>>` may be on a 64-bit arch, since both the value and the flag fits a single 64-bit memory location: https://godbolt.org/z/Ybs31K.

Answer (score 2):

`std::optional<T>` is required to be as TriviallyCopyable as `T` itself is. This was added in a defect report post-C++17, but all `std::optional` implementations ought to implement it.

Comment: But why I need to initialize "value" with std::nullopt? Why std::atomic does not create internal std::optional with std::nullopt initialization?

Comment: @Igor Because default constructor for `std::atomic` with automatic storage duration does not initialize the underlying object.